# Populate table with React state hook from another component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am building a form with many hooks which populates a table when submitted. So far I have all of the functions - everything - in a single App.

```
  const [id, setId] = React.useState<number>(0);
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState<string>('')
  const [middleName, setMiddleName] = React.useState<string>('')
  const [lastName, setLastName] = React.useState<string>('')
  const [birthDay, setBirthDay] = React.useState<number>(0)
  const [birthMonth, setBirthMonth] = React.useState<number | string>(0)
  const [birthYear, setBirthYear] = React.useState<number>(0)
  const [birthState, setBirthState] = React.useState<string>('')
  const [birthCounty, setBirthCounty] = React.useState<string>('')
  const [birthTown, setBirthTown] = React.useState<string>('')
  const [people, setPeople] = React.useState<any[]>([])
```

The final state hook "people" populates a table when the form is submitted. The functions to render the table depend on the people array. Each of the hooks corresponds to a column in the table (save the last hook, which populates the table):

```
  const renderHeader = () => {
    let columns = [
      'id',
      'firstName',
      'middleName',
      'lastName',
      'birthDay',
      'birthMonth',
      'birthYear',
      'birthState',
      'birthCounty',
      'birthTown'
    ]
    if (people.length === 0) {
      return <h3>add people to the array to view table</h3>
    } else if (people.length > 0) {
      return columns.map((col: string, index: number) => {
        return <th key={index}>{col.toUpperCase()}</th>
      });
    }
  }
  const renderBody = () => {
    return people.map(({
      id,
      firstName,
      middleName,
      lastName,
      birthDay,
      birthMonth,
      birthYear,
      birthState,
      birthCounty,
      birthTown 
    }) => {
      return (
        <tr key={id}>
          <td>{id}</td>
          <td>{firstName}</td>
          <td>{middleName}</td>
          <td>{lastName}</td>
          <td>{birthDay}</td>
          <td>{birthMonth}</td>
          <td>{birthYear}</td>
          <td>{birthTown}</td>
          <td>{birthCounty}</td>
          <td>{birthState}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }
```

I want to separate the App into two components: a Form component and a Table component. I am not sure of how to go about passing the people hook to the Table if I separate them. Is there a way to do this without using Redux?

Here is all of the code for reference:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { states } from './states';
import getCounties from './getCounties';

function App() {
  const [id, setId] = React.useState<number>(0);
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = React.useState<string>('')
  const [middleName, setMiddleName] = React.useState<string>('')
  const [lastName, setLastName] = React.useState<string>('')
  const [birthDay, setBirthDay] = React.useState<number>(0)
  const [birthMonth, setBirthMonth] = React.useState<number | string>(0)
  const [birthYear, setBirthYear] = React.useState<number>(0)
  const [birthState, setBirthState] = React.useState<string>('')
  const [birthCounty, setBirthCounty] = React.useState<string>('')
  const [birthTown, setBirthTown] = React.useState<string>('')
  const [people, setPeople] = React.useState<any[]>([])
  
  
  const renderHeader = () => {
    let columns = [
      'id',
      'firstName',
      'middleName',
      'lastName',
      'birthDay',
      'birthMonth',
      'birthYear',
      'birthState',
      'birthCounty',
      'birthTown'
    ]
    if (people.length === 0) {
      return <h3>add people to the array to view table</h3>
    } else if (people.length > 0) {
      return columns.map((col: string, index: number) => {
        return <th key={index}>{col.toUpperCase()}</th>
      });
    }
  }
  const renderBody = () => {
    return people.map(({
      id,
      firstName,
      middleName,
      lastName,
      birthDay,
      birthMonth,
      birthYear,
      birthState,
      birthCounty,
      birthTown 
    }) => {
      return (
        <tr key={id}>
          <td>{id}</td>
          <td>{firstName}</td>
          <td>{middleName}</td>
          <td>{lastName}</td>
          <td>{birthDay}</td>
          <td>{birthMonth}</td>
          <td>{birthYear}</td>
          <td>{birthTown}</td>
          <td>{birthCounty}</td>
          <td>{birthState}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  const handleFirstNameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setFirstName(e.target.value);
  }
  const handleMiddleNameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setMiddleName(e.target.value);
  }
  const handleLastNameChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setLastName(e.target.value);
  }
  const handleBirthYearChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setBirthYear(e.target.valueAsNumber);
  }
  const handleBirthMonthChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setBirthMonth(e.target.value);
  }
  const handleBirthDayChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setBirthDay(e.target.valueAsNumber);
  }
  const handleBirthTownChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setBirthTown(e.target.value);
  }
  const handleBirthCountyChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setBirthCounty(e.currentTarget.value);
  }
  const handleBirthStateChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setBirthState(e.currentTarget.value)
  }

  const onSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setPeople(people => [...people, {
      id,
      firstName,
      middleName,
      lastName,
      birthDay,
      birthMonth,
      birthYear,
      birthState,
      birthCounty,
      birthTown
    }]);
    setId(id + 1);
    setFirstName('');
    setMiddleName('');
    setLastName('');
    setBirthDay(0);
    setBirthMonth('');
    setBirthYear(0);
    setBirthTown('');
    setBirthCounty('');
    setBirthState('');
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1><code>Kyle's Genealogy Thing</code></h1>
      
      <table id="people">
        <thead>
          <tr>{renderHeader()}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {renderBody()}
        </tbody>
      </table> 
      
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div>
          <input
            required
            value={firstName}
            placeholder='first name'
            id='firstName'
            name='firstName'
            onChange={handleFirstNameChange}
          />
          <input
            value={middleName}
            placeholder='middle name'
            id='middleName'
            name='middleName'
            onChange={handleMiddleNameChange}
          />
          <input
            required
            value={lastName}
            placeholder="last name"
            onChange={handleLastNameChange}
          />
          </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="birthDay">day of birth</label>
          <input
            name="birthDay"
            id="birthDay"
            type='number'
            min='1'
            max='31'
            onChange={handleBirthDayChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor='birthMonth'>month of birth</label>
          <input
            name='birthMonth'
            id='birthMonth'
            min='1'
            max='12'
            onChange={handleBirthMonthChange}
            />
          <label htmlFor='birthYear'>year of birth</label>
          <input
            name='birthYear'
            id='birthYear'
            type='number'
            value={birthYear}
            onChange={handleBirthYearChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>state of birth</label>
          <select
            value={birthState}
            placeholder='state of birth'
            onChange={handleBirthStateChange}>
            {states.map(state =>
              <option key={state} value={state}>
                {state}
              </option>
            )}
          </select>
          <label>county of birth</label>
          <select
            value={birthCounty}
            placeholder='county of birth'
            onChange={handleBirthCountyChange}>
            {getCounties(birthState)}
          </select>
          <label>town or city of birth</label>
          <input
            value={birthTown}
            placeholder='town or city of birth'
            onChange={handleBirthTownChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button>submit</button>
      </form> 
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I also wrote an interface to use with people, however I have not been able to implement it…I think that might be another question, but for reference here is the interface I wrote:

```
export interface Place {
  state: string;
  county: string;
  town: string;
}

export interface Date {
  day: number;
  month: number | string;
  year: number;
}

export interface Name {
  first: string;
  middle?: string;
  last: string;
}

export interface Person {
  id: number;
  name: Name;
  birthdate: Date;
  birthplace: Place;
}

export interface People extends Person {
  people: Person[]
}
```

Update:

I've separated the components into the following:
**Form**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Person } from '../Person';
import getCounties from '../getCounties';
import { states } from '../states';

const blankPerson: Person = {
    id: 0,
    firstName: '',
    middleName: '',
    lastName: '',
    birthYear: 0,
    birthMonth: 0,
    birthDay: 0,
    birthState: '',
    birthCounty: '',
    birthTown: ''
}

interface Props {
    onSave: (person: Person) => void
}

export function Form({ onSave }: Props) {
    const [person, setPerson] = React.useState(blankPerson);

    return <>
        <form onSubmit={() => onSave(person)}>
            <div>
                <input
                    required
                    value={person.firstName}
                    placeholder='first name'
                    id='firstName'
                    name='firstName'
                    onChange={e => setPerson({ ...person, firstName: e.target.value })}
                />
                <input
                    value={person.middleName}
                    placeholder='middle name'
                    id='middleName'
                    name='middleName'
                    onChange={e => setPerson({ ...person, middleName: e.target.value })}
                />
                <input
                    required
                    value={person.lastName}
                    placeholder="last name"
                    onChange={e => setPerson({ ...person, lastName: e.target.value })}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label htmlFor="birthDay">day of birth</label>
                <input
                    value={person.birthDay}
                    name="birthDay"
                    id="birthDay"
                    type='number'
                    min='1'
                    max='31'
                    onChange={e => setPerson({ ...person, birthDay: e.target.valueAsNumber })}
                />
                <label htmlFor='birthMonth'>month of birth</label>
                <input
                    value={person.birthMonth}
                    name='birthMonth'
                    id='birthMonth'
                    min='1'
                    max='12'
                    onChange={e => setPerson({ ...person, birthMonth: e.target.valueAsNumber })}
                />
                <label htmlFor='birthYear'>year of birth</label>
                <input
                    name='birthYear'
                    id='birthYear'
                    type='number'
                    value={person.birthYear}
                    onChange={e => setPerson({ ...person, birthYear: e.target.valueAsNumber })}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>state of birth</label>
                <select
                    value={person.birthState}
                    placeholder='state of birth'
                    onChange={e => setPerson({ ...person, birthState: e.target.value })}>
                    {states.map(state =>
                        <option key={state} value={state}>
                            {state}
                        </option>
                    )}
                </select>
                <label>county of birth</label>
                <select
                    value={person.birthCounty}
                    placeholder='county of birth'
                    onChange={e => setPerson({ ...person, birthCounty: e.target.value })}>
                    {getCounties(person.birthState)}
                </select>
                <label>town or city of birth</label>
                <input
                    value={person.birthTown}
                    placeholder='town or city of birth'
                    onChange={e => setPerson({ ...person, birthTown: e.target.value })}
                />
            </div>
            <button>submit</button>
        </form>

    </>
}
```

**Table**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Person } from '../Person';

interface Props {
    people: Person[]
}

export function Table({people}: Props) {
    return <table>{ people.map(person => <tr>
        <td>{person.id}</td>
          <td>{person.firstName}</td>
          <td>{person.middleName}</td>
          <td>{person.lastName}</td>
          <td>{person.birthDay}</td>
          <td>{person.birthMonth}</td>
          <td>{person.birthYear}</td>
          <td>{person.birthTown}</td>
          <td>{person.birthCounty}</td>
          <td>{person.birthState}</td>
    </tr>)}</table>
}
```

And the App tying it all together tying:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Person } from './Person';
import {Form} from './Form/Form';
import {Table} from './Table/Table';

function App() {
const [people, setPeople] = React.useState<Person[]>([])
 function addPerson(person: Person) {
    setPeople([...people, person])
  }
return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1><code>Kyle's Genealogy Thing</code></h1>
      <Form onSave={addPerson}/>
      <Table people={people}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

but now the Table isn't updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you end with three major components here.

- Form
- Table
- Parent (contains the form and the table)

First of all, it will be a lot easier if you model a single person as it's own interface. You will be using this a lot. Something like:

```
export interface Person {
  id: number
  firstName: string
  middleName: string
  lastName: string
  // etc...
}
```

---

### Form

Now you can make a form component takes a function as a prop. This function accepts a whole `Person` object as an argument. This form component doesn't care what this function does. All it needs to do is call it with the person that it completed. It will be up the parent component to provide this function.

```
interface Props {
  onSave: (person: Person) => void
}

const blankPerson: Person = {
  id: 0,
  firstName: '',
  middleName: '',
  lastName: '',
  // etc...
}

export function MyForm({ onSave }: Props) {
  const [person, setPerson] = React.useState(blankPerson);

  return <>
    {/* ... */}
    <form onSubmit={() => onSave(person)}>
      <input
        required
        value={person.firstName}
        placeholder='first name'
        id='firstName'
        name='firstName'
        onChange={e => setPerson({ ...person, firstName: e.target.value })}
      />
    </form>
  </>
}
```

Note that now instead of:

```
setFirstName(e.target.value)
```

You do:

```
setPerson({ ...person, firstName: e.target.value })
```

Setting the fields is a bit more cumbersome, but having many less state instances is worth it.

---

### Table

Now the table, this one is easy. It doesn't even need state, just props.

```
interface Props {
  people: Person[]
}

export function MyTable({ people }: Props) {
  return <table>{ people.map(person => <tr>...</tr> }</table>
}
```

---

### Parent

Lastly, the parent that ties them together.

Here is where you keep the list of people. The goal is to provide the plumbing required to let the form add a person (via `setPeople`), and to provide the current list of people to the table (via `people`).

In other words, your form is the "setter" of your state, and the table is the read only data of that same state.

```
function EditablePeopleList() {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState<Person[]>([])

  function addPerson(person: Person) {
    setPeople([...people, person])
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <MyForm onSave={addPerson} />
      <MyTable people={people} />
    <div>
  )
}
```

---

The point is to keep state as local as possible. The table doesn't need to know the state of the form, and the form doesn't need to know the state of the table. But there is a parent component that provides the data and functions to update `people` to it's children as props.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Alex, this is very intuitive and makes a lot of sense. The only thing I'm a little confused about are the rest of my state hooks. I can just ditch them and have everything in the one people state hook, because it's within the interface of Person?

Comment: State can track any value. It can be a boolean, or a string, or a complex object. In general if different bits of state are very tightly coupled (such as different properties of the same entity) it's best track them as one state. That said you could use the approach I've outline while still tracking each field as its own state. You would just have to assemble the full person from all those states before you send it to `onSave({ id, firstName, ...etc })`

Comment: Alex, how would I go about incrementing the id to preserve a unique value for every entry? I was previously doing that via the onSubmit function after capturing the inputs.

Comment: Lot's of ways, but I would probably change `addPerson` so set something like `setPeople([...people, { ...person, id: people.length + 1 }])` That way your form doesn't have to care about the id.

Comment: Everything is looking good until I submit, at which point the Table doesn't update. I updated the question at the bottom with the code provided…maybe I implemented the table columns incorrectly?

Comment: Is `onSave` or `addPerson` getting called at all? Add a `console.log('called addPerson')` to that function and see if it triggers. Maybe your `<button>` needs to be a `<input type="submit">` instead? Add some console.log's around and see if you can pinpoint where things disconnect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234634/discussion-between-kyle-and-alex-wayne).

Answer (score 0):

Just pass people state as a props in your table component like this.

Your seperate table component:

```
const Table = (props) => {
const {people} = props;

  const renderHeader = () => {
    let columns = [
      'id',
      'firstName',
      'middleName',
      'lastName',
      'birthDay',
      'birthMonth',
      'birthYear',
      'birthState',
      'birthCounty',
      'birthTown'
    ]
    if (people.length === 0) {
      return <h3>add people to the array to view table</h3>
    } else if (people.length > 0) {
      return columns.map((col: string, index: number) => {
        return <th key={index}>{col.toUpperCase()}</th>
      });
    }
  }
  const renderBody = () => {
    return people.map(({
      id,
      firstName,
      middleName,
      lastName,
      birthDay,
      birthMonth,
      birthYear,
      birthState,
      birthCounty,
      birthTown 
    }) => {
      return (
        <tr key={id}>
          <td>{id}</td>
          <td>{firstName}</td>
          <td>{middleName}</td>
          <td>{lastName}</td>
          <td>{birthDay}</td>
          <td>{birthMonth}</td>
          <td>{birthYear}</td>
          <td>{birthTown}</td>
          <td>{birthCounty}</td>
          <td>{birthState}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  return <table id="people">
        <thead>
          <tr>{renderHeader()}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {renderBody()}
        </tbody>
      </table> 
}
```

And then in yout main component just import your new Table component:

```
<Table people={people} />
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get errors about the hooks having an implicit any type. (ts7031) I cast the types in the App.

Comment: Sorry for not able to provide a complete solution. You are using ts, maybe you need to modify a little bit of language-specific syntax, but the core part is we need to pass props.